# Anchor tag causing right side space after its inline img element how to remove that and align menu items properly

Tags: html, css

I am creating a Menu bar for my website, this includes a left side logo image and right side menu items. The logo is an inline element of anchor tag as I need a feature where if somebody clicks on a logo, then it should go to index.html (home page).

This anchor tag is adding extra space after image which is creating two problems 1) hyperlink work far right of the image and last menu items comes on the second line.

I already tried every possible way, for example, removing space between `a>img>/a>` or using `style="display: block;"`, and many more. How can I properly align the menu items and remove the extra right size hyperlink area after the logo image?

```css
.header_top {

    width: auto;
    max-width: 72em;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

}

.navbar-toggleable-md {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: .1rem;
    margin-bottom: .1rem;
}

.bg-faded {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* padding: 1.1em 1em; */
    padding: 21px 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-nav {

    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    padding-left: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


.mx-auto {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}




li.nav-item.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #C19506;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}
ul.navbar-nav li {
    margin: 0 6px;
}

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header_top" id="home">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-faded">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img width="37%" height="37%" src="images/Logo.png"></a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Contac</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Contac</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Please use any 1285px x 249px image for logo or download it from  https://www.filedropper.com/logo_9 as I am unable to upload image.
you will notice between the logo image and first menu item 'Home' the Anchor tag occupies more width than the image.
If possible, is there any other way to add a link with  tag.

Comment: I tryed your code on jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/42pg7fre/ 
I replace the logo img with one with the provided sizes. I don't see any problem if that the logo is very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `width` of `<img>` from any percentage to some fixed values like `100px`.

This will solve your extra space problem added by anchor tag but for responsiveness, you have to adjust the `width` as per different screen sizes.

```css
.header_top {

    width: auto;
    max-width: 72em;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

}

.navbar-toggleable-md {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: .1rem;
    margin-bottom: .1rem;
}

.bg-faded {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* padding: 1.1em 1em; */
    padding: 21px 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-nav {

    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    padding-left: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


.mx-auto {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}




li.nav-item.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #C19506;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}
ul.navbar-nav li {
    margin: 0 6px;
}

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header_top" id="home">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-faded">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img width="100px" height="auto" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D12AQG20nwV6xq8lQ/article-cover_image-shrink_600_2000/0?e=1565222400&v=beta&t=-kqjXSTS6VCDVj8UX6ORuqrxKCDTR9BQwDAsycIfUio"></a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Contac</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Contac</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Om Prakash, the approach you told worked perfectly.